# Extracting the contents of the ist and dynamically doing calculations

Tags: java

I am getting an list from Hibernate criteria as shown below ...

```
List<dddObject> abcObjectsList= session.createCriteria(dddObject.class)
```

upon inspecting while  I am getting data in this format

```
abcObjectsList= ArrayList<E>
     elementData =Object[3]
        [0] = Long  ----------> value 23
        [1] = Integer -------> value 20
        [0] = Long  ----------> value 32
        [1] =Integer -------> value 20
        [0] =Long  ----------> value 43
        [1] =Integer -------> value 18
```

I have stored it in a map in such a way as I was requiring it in same fashion

```
  Map<Long, Integer> result = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
            for (Object[] arr : list) {
                result.put((Long) arr[0], (Integer) arr[1]);
            }
   Key      Value
    23      20
    32      20  (20+20  =40 , min=23 max=32)
    43      18
```

Now Please advise the logic as I have to implement the logic in such a way such that if
the value of map is 40 then the min value is 23(Key) and max value is 32(key) and this
logic of 40 is configurable it can increase to 60 or 80 in nearby future so I have declared it a constant.

```
final int BARRIER = 40;
```

Now this max and min musty agin be stored in a seprate ma named final map whose key is max and value is min as shown below..

```
Key      Value
23         32
```

please advise how can I achieve this in java. any help would be appreciated

folks please advise for this, lem  me know if any further clarification reuires.any early help would be much appreciatedThanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407794/extracting-value-from-one-map-and-putting-it-on-second-map-based-on-some-conditi

Comment: @Funtik I am different user and that person is someone else I have written with my approach can you please advise on this.

Comment: even if you're a different person, the question is the same :)

Comment: @Futnik Aghreed but this time I am more focussed on my problem can you please advise the solutioin for this.

Comment: I could not understand the question. Try rephrasing it.

Comment: @futnik even if you can please provide the solution for this one it will answer my question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410808/splitting-a-map-based-on-certain-condition?noredirect=1#comment32299056_21410808