# Splitting a map based on certain condition

Tags: java

I have a map as shown below:

```
Key        Value
    23      20
    32      20      (20+20  =40 , min=23 max=32)
    43      18
    45      24      (24+18 =42 , since 42 >40 so here min and max will be same that is 43
    47      10    
    56      6       (24 +10 +6 =40) so here min =45 and max = 56
    49       2  
    47      12
```

As you can see, there will be final constant named split whose value is 40

```
final int SPLIT = 40;  //this will be configurable as it value can be changed.
```

I have to implement the logic such as if the value of the map reaches 40,
then the first key of the map from where the calculation started and the key where exactly it reaches to 40 will be chosen as min and max also, as explained above.

Besides this, care needs to be taken if sum reaches more than 40. If so, we have to ignore it and take the previous value itself as min and max in the case where min and max would be equal.

Please suggest me how can I achieve this with Java and `Map`.  folks please advise

The data that I am geeting is not from database I am geeting it from hibernate criteria in an object list

I am getting an list from Hibernate criteria as shown below ...

```
  List<Object[]> abcObjectsList= session.createCriteria(dddObject.class)
```

upon inspecting while  I am getting data in this format

```
abcObjectsList= ArrayList<E>
     elementData =Object[3]
        [0] = Long  ----------> value 23
        [1] = Integer -------> value 20
        [0] = Long  ----------> value 32
        [1] =Integer -------> value 20
        [0] =Long  ----------> value 43
        [1] =Integer -------> value 18
```

I have stored it in a map in such a way as I was requiring it in same fashion

```
  Map<Long, Integer> result = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
            for (Object[] arr : list) {
                result.put((Long) arr[0], (Integer) arr[1]);
            }
```

so finally map will contain..

```
  Key      Value
        23      20
        32      20  (20+20  =40 , min=23 max=32)
        43      18
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting the contents of the ist and dynamically doing calculations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409397/extracting-the-contents-of-the-ist-and-dynamically-doing-calculations)

Comment: no this is not same question being asked , please advise on the solution

Comment: @user1694073 What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @ZouZou I am stuck up on the problem can you please advise the solution.

Comment: I've edited your question with better grammar and syntax to help the readers. If you feel that I changed the scope or meaning of some parts, feel free to revert them!

Comment: @user1694073 You're stuck on what exaclty? How do you store these key/value pairs? In a `LinkedHashMap`? How do you check if the split value has not been exceeded? Please show that you did some research on your problem.

Comment: @ZouZou I have updated but that not a correct appraoch e\request you to pleease explain with context to Map

Comment: @user1694073 This is the same question... Are you kidding? How it differs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a Map, you could create a `Pair` class that will hold the key and the value.

```
class Pair {
    public int key;
    public int value;

    public Pair(int key, int value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then create a list of pair and iterate through it. If the sum is 0, initialize the min and the max. Then for each pair iterated, add its value to the sum. If the sum is inferior continue the loop and update the max key, else you have two cases possible:

1. The sum is equals to the limit so update the max key
2. The sum is not equals to the limit (so it's superior), decrement the index and don't update the max key

---

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    List<Integer> indexList = Arrays.asList(23,32,43,45,47,56,49,47); // get this from database
    List<Integer> valueList = Arrays.asList(20,20,18,24,10,6,2,12); // get this from database
    List<Pair> pairList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < indexList.size();i++){
        pairList.add(new Pair(indexList.get(i), valueList.get(i)));
    }
    int sum = 0;
    int min = -1;
    int max = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < pairList.size(); i++){
        Pair p = pairList.get(i);
        if(sum == 0){
            min = p.key;
            max = p.key;
        }
        sum += p.value;
        if(sum < LIMIT){
            max = p.key;
        } else {
            if(sum > LIMIT){
                i--;
            } else {
                max = p.key;
            }
            System.out.println(min+"_"+max);
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
23_32
43_43
45_56
```

I show you how to create a list of pair through your map (use a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve insertion order) (obviously, you'll need to modify a little bit the `Pair` class):

```
Map<Long, Integer> m = new LinkedHashMap<>();
//fill your map here
List<Pair> l = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map.Entry<Long, Integer> entries : m.entrySet()){
    l.add(new Pair(entries.getKey(), entries.getValue()));
}
//Now you have a list of Pair
```

Comment: can you please see the updated post in which I have shown how I am fetching data and finally storing it in map and from this map we have to do the process.

Comment: @user1694073 You have the idea of how do to this. This is the exactly the same process with a Map (you'll have to use a `LinkedHashMap` instead to preserve the insertion order when iterating).

Comment: i think slightest change will take place in your program now , where we have to remove the portion wher we are saying that we are fetching the list from database in your code

Comment: @user1694073 You have a `Map<Long, Integer>` instead of a `Pair(int ,int)`. There is not much changes because each key/value pair corresponds to my Pair class I defined. Where are you stuck?

Comment: can you please then update your main method so that I can grasp clearly with the updated changes Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1694073 Do you understand what I did or not?

Comment: there will be slightest changes will be done inside the main method , request you to please update the main method once again

Comment: @user1694073 Answer my question please. Did you understand what I did or not?

Comment: I understand partially but please understand the data I am getting is from List<Object[]> abcObjectsList= session.createCriteria(dddObject.class) and it is an object form

Comment: these values are hardcoded List<Integer> indexList = Arrays.asList(23,32,43,45,47,56,49,47); // get this from database
    List<Integer> valueList = Arrays.asList(20,20,18,24,10,6,2,12); for understanding but in real it is coming from the method shown above

Comment: @user1694073 From this `List<Object[]>`, you are getting a `Map<Long, Integer>` so where is the problem? As I said each key/value pair of this map is exaclty the same as each Pair object I defined. The both lists are hardcoded to show you a compilable and working example.

Comment: how I will fetch indexList  valueList in my case , thats why I was focussing to update the main method please

Comment: Thanks I have grasped but if i want to remove the hardcoded indexlist and value list and i want that in indexlist and value list values should be come up from map then what i need to do in that case

Comment: i wil be really greateful to you if you could please update the codethat will clear my understanding exactly thanks in advance

Comment: @user1694073 I showed you how to create a list of Pair object with your map.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am rfeally thankful to you for putting that much effort Thanks I thinnk now from there would be no more change

Comment: so the final main method would be like..List<Pair> l = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map.Entry<Long, Integer> entries : m.entrySet()){
    l.add(new Pair(entries.getKey(), entries.getValue()));
}int sum = 0;
    int min = -1;
    int max = -1;
and from there onwards the program would be the same

Comment: @user1694073 Why don't you try? You'll need to modify a bit the Pair class.

Comment: @user1694073 It seems like you are new here. If an answer has helped you don't forget to accept it by clicking the tick mark. Thanks!

Comment: I have accepted the answer can you please also advise what modifications need to be done in pair class, Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1694073 Are you a programmer? I mean it's very basic stuff, instead of two int attributes, you have one Long and another which is Integer.

Comment: I have accept the answer , I agree , But request you tp please advise , Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1694073 Can you answer my question please? This is not a code-for-you site. So are you a programmer? If yes, this is very basic stuff and you should be able to do this alone. If no then hire someone to program this for you. I've already done 95% of your question. I think you'll be able to do the 5% left.

Comment: I am starting programmer but I am really thankful; to you , You have help me a lot, but request you tp please at least give me the hint what changes need to be done in pair class thanks a lot

Comment: @user1694073 Ok I created a Pair class with two attributes of type int. You want to use one of type Long and another of type Integer. What should you do?

Comment: @user1694073 Ok, and what constructor should you define?

Comment: We'll that I do not know can you please advise for that.

Comment: @user1694073 Read this please. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html. Come back when you'll have found how to do what I asked.

Comment: I have implemented the logic finally but still it is not working properly  , can you pls recheck it

Comment: @user1694073 Then post what you've done, how would I check it then?

Comment: Please try to understand the one condition missing in the logic is that lets if at the initial level the value of particular key 25 is 60 value at the starting itself and our barrier is 40 the obviosly rite now we are putting min and max same that is 25 , but this should not happen , the way it should happen is that it should divide the value by 4 and assign the vision to 25 key so in this case 25 key would be 4 times in the list as 25 key having value 15(60/4)

Comment: and also this check where value is greater than key and we are dividing the value by 4 and then assigning the values to the key in the list this check should happen at the initial level itself before iterating the list

Comment: @user1694073 You're showing no efforts about what you did, what you tried. You're only giving me your requirements since the beginning. Hire a programmer instead. This is not a code-for-you site.