# extracting data from the list on a certain condition

Tags: java, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I have a map as shown below:

```
Key        Value
    23      20
    32      20      (20+20  =40 , min=23 max=32)
    43      18
    45      24      (24+18 =42 , since 42 >40 so here min and max will be same that is 43
    47      10    
    56      6       (24 +10 +6 =40) so here min =45 and max = 56
    43       50    ****so how we will handle the case where value is greater  than            key 50 >43 ********
```

so i have implemented the logic which will take the

1) where value of map value reaches 40
2) where the map value upon calculation becomes greater than 40

3) **** haven't implemented the scenario in where first instance where the value of map at initial level is greater at first instance let say as shown above the key is 43 and the value is 50******

Now please advise how to handle the third scenario, what I have implemented is ..
create a `Pair` class that will hold the key and the value.

```
class Pair {
    public int key;
    public int value;

    public Pair(int key, int value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

hen create a list of pair and iterate through it. If the sum is 0, initialize the min and the max. Then for each pair iterated, add its value to the sum. If the sum is inferior continue the loop and update the max key, else you have two cases possible:

1. The sum is equals to the limit so update the max key
2. The sum is not equals to the limit (so it's superior), decrement the index and don't update the max key

---

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
 Map<Long, Integer> m = new LinkedHashMap<>();
//fill your map here
List<Pair> l = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map.Entry<Long, Integer> entries : m.entrySet()){
    l.add(new Pair(entries.getKey(), entries.getValue()));
}

//Now you have a list of Pair
    int sum = 0;
    int min = -1;
    int max = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < pairList.size(); i++){
        Pair p = pairList.get(i);
        if(sum == 0){
            min = p.key;
            max = p.key;
        }
        sum += p.value;
        if(sum < LIMIT){
            max = p.key;
        } else {
            if(sum > LIMIT){
                i--;
            } else {
                max = p.key;
            }
            System.out.println(min+"_"+max);
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
23_32
43_43
45_56
```

Can you please advise how to handle the third scenario  where first instance where the value of map at initial level is greater at first instance let say as shown above the key is 43 and the value is 50******

Comment: Just as a backlink for others who are trying to understand what the question is about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410808/splitting-a-map-based-on-certain-condition

Answer (score 0):

You still did not really specify *clearly* what you are going to achieve. You did not say whether the keys of your input map are in ascending order (that is, whether it is a TreeMap). In the original question (linked in the first comment), your input was 2 lists. The example that you posted does not make any sense at all, because it contains the key=43 *twice* - so it can't be a map. Your description sounds like there is some constraint between the keys and the values (the value 50 being greater than the key 43), but maybe this is just an artifact of your explaination.

Your solution approach, and how you updated some variables in your implementation, may be an attempt to give precise information. But maybe a verbal or semi-formal description of your actual **goal** are more helpful here. Maybe you just can not *explain* what you want to achieve. In the worst case, you don't *know* it.

At the moment, my interpretation is roughly the following: Your input consists of two lists (!). And you are trying to find ranges of the first list, so that the sum of the corresponding values in the second list is at least 40.

IF this is the case, you can just compute the *indices* for the list of values where the summation should start and where the summation should end. When you have these *indices*, you can obtain the corresponding "keys" from the first list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SumSplit
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        keys.add(23);
        keys.add(32);
        keys.add(43);
        keys.add(45);
        keys.add(47);
        keys.add(56);
        keys.add(43);

        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        values.add(20);
        values.add(20);
        values.add(18);
        values.add(24);
        values.add(10);
        values.add( 6);
        values.add(50);

        final int SPLIT_VALUE = 40;

        List<Integer> minIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> maxIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int sum = 0;
        int minIndex = -1;
        for (int i=0; i<keys.size(); i++)
        {
            Integer value = values.get(i);
            sum += value;

            if (minIndex == -1)
            {
                minIndex = i;
            }
            if (sum >= SPLIT_VALUE)
            {
                minIndices.add(minIndex);
                maxIndices.add(i);
                minIndex = -1;
                sum = 0;
            }
        }


        for (int i=0; i<minIndices.size(); i++)
        {
            Integer min = minIndices.get(i);
            Integer max = maxIndices.get(i);
            System.out.println("min: "+keys.get(min)+", max "+keys.get(max));
            printInfo(min, max, keys, values);
        }
    }

    private static void printInfo(int min, int max, List<Integer> keys, List<Integer> values)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=min; i<=max; i++)
        {
            Integer key = keys.get(i);
            Integer value = values.get(i);
            sum += value;
            System.out.println("    "+key+" : "+value+"   (sum until now: "+sum+")");
        }
        System.out.println("Sum: "+sum);
    }
}
```

If this is not what you are going to achieve, please describe *clearly* what your actual goal is.